# Move/Rotate a bone with Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bones, rigify

Is there a way to rotate/move a bone using geometry nodes?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No. I'm very sorry.

Comment: a bone is not geometry ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly affect a bone with geometry nodes.  But, you can move a vertex with geometry nodes, and by using bone constraints, you can follow the motions of vertices with bones.

My basic structure for doing things to bones with vertices looks like this:

[image]

I have a mesh that represents my basis vectors, and I've marked those vectors by assigning them to vertex groups.  (One of these vectors is redundant, but it's nicer to see, to understand the concept.)  After that, I can use a few bone constraints to follow those:

[image]

Those constraints are what I'd typically use (copy transforms or child-of from vertex groups are ambiguous concepts, so I use the unambiguous damped track and locked track.)  We can see that the bone follows the geometry nodes transform given the mesh.

You didn't ask about scale, which *is* possible, but which is significantly more complicated.

Comment: I never thought that it can be done it this way.
Thanks Nathan!